# Python Twisted twisted.internet

Tags: python, installation, pip, twisted

I've downloaded twisted from git

git clone -b trunk https://github.com/twisted/twisted.git

as http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads suggests.

And then I performed

sudo python setup.py install

But now when I run some python files I get

ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.

I've also noticed, in the README.rst of git, that it doens't mention the module twisted.internet.

So where should I get it?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install Twisted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever `sudo pip install ...` anything.  Use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) instead.

```
exarkun@baryon:~$ virtualenv /tmp/virtualenv-demo
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
New python executable in /tmp/virtualenv-demo/bin/python2
Also creating executable in /tmp/virtualenv-demo/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
exarkun@baryon:~$ . /tmp/virtualenv-demo/bin/activate
(virtualenv-demo) exarkun@baryon:~$ pip install twisted
Collecting twisted
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from twisted)
  Using cached constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting zope.interface>=3.6.0 (from twisted)
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from twisted)
  Using cached Automat-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from twisted)
  Using cached incremental-16.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /tmp/virtualenv-demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted)
Collecting attrs (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted)
  Using cached attrs-16.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in /tmp/virtualenv-demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /tmp/virtualenv-demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools->zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in /tmp/virtualenv-demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from setuptools->zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /tmp/virtualenv-demo/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted)
Installing collected packages: constantly, zope.interface, attrs, Automat, incremental, twisted
Successfully installed Automat-0.5.0 attrs-16.3.0 constantly-15.1.0 incremental-16.10.1 twisted-17.1.0 zope.interface-4.3.3
(virtualenv-demo) exarkun@baryon:~$ python -c 'import twisted.internet; print twisted.internet'
<module 'twisted.internet' from '/tmp/virtualenv-demo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/__init__.pyc'>
(virtualenv-demo) exarkun@baryon:~$ deactivate 
exarkun@baryon:~$
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But when I type the command python -c 'import twisted.internet; print twisted.internet', I get

File "<string>", line 1
    import twisted.internet; print twisted.internet
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Perhaps you're using Python 3 and you have to use print as a function instead of a statement.  The `python -c ...` line was just a demonstrate that Twisted was properly installed.  You don't _have_ to do that step.  You could just try running whatever Twisted-based code you have (making sure to use the Python executable from the virtualenv - it will be in your $PATH so it should work - just don't hard-code /usr/bin/python or anything like that anywhere).